# how can I fit body content of 'div' into that 'div'?

Tags: html, css

I have to fix a 'div' element's body correctly and not able to do it.

my CSS code is

```
.bgImageMobile {
    height: 670px !important;
    width: 455px !important;
    background-size: 425px contain;
    background-image: url('./nexus600.png');
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    align: center !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 8px; } 

.dynamicWidgetDivMobile {
    height: 647px !important;
    width: 407px !important;
    padding: 59px 36px 49px 22px !important;
    margin: 0px 27px 0px 0px;
    FLOAT: LEFT; }
```

my div and its body look like this

[image]

My Actual HTML

```
<div id="mobileDiv" class="bgImageMobile" ng-show="showMobile" align="center">   <div id="innerDiv" class="dynamicWidgetDivMobile">

<iframe
 src="mobilePreview.jsp?dt=dt&wid=wid"   
        style="zoom:0.60;height:100%;width:100%;min-height:750px;"  
 width="99.6%" frameborder="0"></iframe>    </div> </div>
```

I wrote this HTML code in a innerHTML format in a JSP page.

I need to align the content into the div properly and the marked borders must be shown inside div.

---

My Actual HTML

```
<div id="mobileDiv" class="bgImageMobile" ng-show="showMobile" align="center">   <div id="innerDiv" class="dynamicWidgetDivMobile">

<iframe
 src="mobilePreview.jsp?dt=dt&wid=wid"   
        style="zoom:0.60;height:100%;width:100%;min-height:750px;"  
 width="99.6%" frameborder="0"></iframe>    </div> </div>
```

I wrote this HTML code in a innerHTML format in a JSP page.

Comment: First make sure that the body has No margin and padding.

Comment: Why are you using a lot of `!important`? it is bad practice.

Comment: You should make sure your `body`'s `width` is set to **100%**.

Comment: Posting your actual HTML would help

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your content div is inside div you applying align.

ex:

```
<div id="mobileDiv" class="bgImageMobile" ng-show="showMobile">
   <div id="innerDiv" class="dynamicWidgetDivMobile">
   <iframe src="mobilePreview.jsp?dt=dt&wid=wid" style="zoom:0.60;height:100%;width:100%;"frameborder="0"></iframe>
   </div>
</div>
```

Your min-height:750px in iframe here can't be 750px because in your CSS container's height is 647px;

Change your CSS:

```
.bgImageMobile {
    height: 670px !important;
    width: 455px !important;
    background-size: 425px contain;
    background-image: url('./nexus600.png');
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 8px; } 

.dynamicWidgetDivMobile {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
     }
```

Comment: I found a solution myself.